# jQuery Cycle plugin

Tags: jquery

So i am messing with the jQuery cycle pluin.. so far i got it to do 50% of what i need.  I am able to cycle through the DIVs that i want. THey show content on my home page, and a unique image for each.

```
<div class="tabContainer slideshow">
    <div class="tab current" style="background:#fff url({iw_value name='dcr.main.tab_bg'/}) no-repeat top left;">
    </div>

    <div class="tab" style="background:#fff url({iw_value name='dcr.main2.tab_bg'/}) no-repeat top left;">
    </div>

    <div class="tab" style="background:#fff url({iw_value name='dcr.main3.tab_bg'/}) no-repeat top left;">
    </div>

    <div class="tab" style="background:#fff url({iw_value name='dcr.main4.tab_bg'/}) no-repeat top left;">
    </div>

</div>
```

I also have links that i would like to be able to cycle along with the images...

```
<ul class="tabNav">
        <li class="current"><a href="#">{iw_value name='dcr.main.tab_title'/}</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">{iw_value name='dcr.main2.tab_title'/}</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">{iw_value name='dcr.main3.tab_title'/}</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">{iw_value name='dcr.main4.tab_title'/}</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">{iw_value name='dcr.main5.tab_title'/}</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">{iw_value name='dcr.main6.tab_title'/}</a></li>

    </ul>
```

The a:active link changes color, and has a background image signifying its active state... how would i go about syncing these two together to  so that they DIVs cycle along with the a href links?

Answer (score 0):

If you are using the jquery cycle plugin at jquery.malsup.com then you can use the page command and style accordingly.

http://jquery.malsup.com/cycle/pager.html

Comment: Awesome...works great... Follow up if I may.  I was able to figure out how to pause it, via: pause: 1,, but i wanted to throw a transparent .png pause icon over the div once the visitor hovers over the div... possible?

Comment: Will have a look tonight and see what I can figure out but it should be possible to attach a callback to the pause function. This will then  run you can run your over code to place the pause icon over the top of the slider.

Can you post a link to the page you are currently working on or even just the samples of the code you are currently using?